# Nth order derivative

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

The question is to find the nth order derivative of $\cos^9x $ . I don't know if there is a fixed form for nth order derivative for cosines or sines in exponents but I tried to see whether there would be any pattern after differentiating 1 or 2 times . But it only got more complicated.

Comment: You should get 5 terms: $sin^9$, $sin^7.cos^2$, $sin^5.cos^4$, $sin^3.cos^6$, $sin.cos^8$

Comment: From CAS: $\frac{\partial ^n\cos ^9(x)}{\partial x^n}=\frac{1}{512} i^n \sum _{k=0}^9 \binom{9}{k} (2 k-9)^n \exp
   (i (2 k-9) x)$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk can you explain how you got that ?

Comment: in Maple I wrote `diff(cos(x)^9,x$n)`. I do not know what the algorithm is behind this.

Comment: why do you need these derivatives? Have you looked at the $n$-th derivative of $\cos^2x$ and $\cos^3 x$ to try to indentify a pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are *two* (slightly more general) approaches.

---

If you are familiar with the complex representation of $\cos(x)$, namely

$$\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2,$$

then it becomes pretty straight forward. Then you have

$$\cos^n(x)=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}e^{ixk}e^{-ix(n-k)}=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}e^{ix(2k-n)}.$$

Now the $N$-th derivative is

$$(\cos^n(x))^{(N)}=\frac{i^N}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}(2k-n)^Ne^{ix(2k-n)}.$$

But to reformulate this in a nice real-valued form might be hard. So here another approach. We generalize the problem to find the $N$-th derivative of

$$f(x)=\sum_{m,n}a_{mn}\cos^m(x)\sin^n(x)$$

with $m$ and $n$ ranging over $\Bbb Z$ and the $a_{mn}$ choosen appropriately, so the sum stays finite. At first, note

$$f'(x)=\sum_{m,n}a_{mn}(m\cos^{m-1}(x)(-\sin^{n+1}(x))+n\sin^{n-1}(x)\cos^{m+1}(x))$$

by only applying chain and product rule. We see further that this is the same as

\begin{align}
f'(x)&=-\sum_{m,n}ma_{mn}\sin^{n+1}(x)\cos^{m-1}(x)+\sum_{m,n}na_{mn}\cos^{m+1}(x)\sin^{n-1}(x)\\
&=-\sum_{m,n}(m+1)a_{m+1,n-1}\sin^n(x)\cos^m(x)+\sum_{m,n}(n+1)a_{m-1,n+1}\cos^m(x)\sin^n(x)\\
&=\sum_{m,n}a^{(1)}_{mn}\cos^m(x)\sin^n(x)
\end{align}

with $a^{(1)}_{mn}=(n+1)a_{m-1,n+1}-(m+1)a_{m+1,n-1}$. Now you can iteratively compute $a^{(N)}_{mn}$ for $N\geq 2$ to get your final answer. For your task you want to start with $a_{mn}=a^{(0)}_{mn}=1$ for $(m,n)=(9,0)$ and zero everywhere else. Maybe one can see a nice pattern emerging when computing the coefficients. I will have to look at it later.